# Median-of-$3$ quicksort probability

Tags: probability, sorting

Consider modifying the Partition procedure of Quicksort by randomly picking three elements from array $A$ and use the median of the three elements as the pivot. What is the exact probability (not asymptotic form) of getting a split with the sizes of both subarrays are at least $|A|/4$?

Assumption:$|A|$ is divisible by $4$ and the pivot element does not count as an element in any one of the two subarrays after the partition

I somehow can find the solution by using summation and product notation.
However, is there any method that can find the solution without using summation and product notation?

Comment: This appears to be copy-pasted from some external source: e.g., https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/problem-6-17-pts-consider-modifying-partition-procedure-quicksort-randomly-picking-three-e-q57592817, https://www.coursehero.com/file/p7ddn0o8/5-Problem-5-17-pts-To-celebrate-the-finishing-of-the-final-exams-you-get-drunk/, https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/17-pts-consider-modifying-partition-procedure-quicksort-randomly-picking-three-elements-ar-q57767195.

Comment: [Plagiarism](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).  You must credit the source of all copied material.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3843632/14578, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64079647/781723. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $|A|=4k$.

The subarray of everything smaller than the pivot will have fewer than $k$ elements exactly when the pivot is one of the $k$ smallest elements of the array. This, in turn, happens, when at least $2$ of the $3$ elements we picked are among the $k$ smallest elements.

This happens with probability $$\frac{\binom k3}{\binom{4k}{3}} + \frac{\binom k2 \binom{3k}{1}}{\binom{4k}{3}}.$$
The first fraction is the probability of choosing $3$ elements from the $k$ smallest, and the second fraction is the probability of choosing exactly $2$ elements from the $k$ smallest, and one from the other $3k$.

The expression doesn't really simplify as such, but we can write it as $\frac{5}{32} - \frac{3}{16(2k-1)} + \frac{3}{32(4k-1)}$ to make it clear what its limit is.

Finally, if the above probability is $p$, we want $1-2p$ as our final answer: we want to exclude the event above, as well as the symmetric event that the other subarray will be small. This gives us a final answer of
$$
   \frac{11}{16} + \frac{3}{8(2k-1)} - \frac{3}{16(4k-1)}.
$$

Comment: By looking at the final answer, when k = 1, answer = 0 but I think this is incorrect, answer should be = 0. I am finding where is the error

Comment: Oh, I found the probability that you *do* get a small array. We should subtract this from $1$. (When $k=1$, we always get a $2:1$ split, and so the answer should be $1$.)

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you